ANSIBLE_COLLECTION_PATH explanation
I'm used to test my roles with molecule on a docker container, everything works fine except a behaviour I don't explain.
When running tests from the collections folder, molecule recreates an ansible_collections directory, reinstalling everything detailled on galaxy.yml.
I don't find the way to not create this directory, as it already exists, could someone help me ?
(venv) user@2175d1d9ed54:~/ansible/ansible_collections/datcollection/infra$ tree
.
|-- CHANGELOG.md
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- README.md
|-- ansible.cfg
|-- galaxy.yml
|-- meta
|   -- runtime.yml
|-- molecule
|   |-- default
|   |   |-- converge.yml
|   |   |-- molecule.yml
|   |   |-- prepare.yml
|   |   -- verify.yml

When I run for example :
(venv) user@2175d1d9ed54:~/ansible/ansible_collections/datcollection/infra$ molecule create -s test
it creates the ansible_collection into the infra folder, and I end with this :
.
|-- CHANGELOG.md
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- README.md
|-- ansible.cfg
|-- galaxy.yml
|-- meta
|   `-- runtime.yml
|-- molecule
|   |-- default
|   |   |-- converge.yml
|   |   |-- molecule.yml
|   |   |-- prepare.yml
|   |   `-- verify.yml
|-- ansible_collections
|   |-- datcollection
|   |   |-- infra
|   |       |-- .yamllint
|   |       |-- CHANGELOG.md
|   |       |-- FILES.json
|   |       |-- LICENSE.txt
|   |       |-- MANIFEST.json
|   |       |-- README.md
|   |       |-- ansible.cfg
|   |       |-- ansible_collections/
|   |       |-- meta/
|   |       |-- molecule/
|   |       |-- plugins/
|   |       |-- roles/

How to tell molecule that the collections are into ~/ansible to avoid recreating that folder, as collections are already installed.
I expect, when running the test, that it just don't recreate the ansible_collection directory into ~/ansible/ansible_collections/datcollection/infra
Tried with provisionner: env: ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATH into individual molecule.yml files, but with no success, the nested dir always recreates.
This does not block role testing, but I feel like there is something not well configured.
